# Музыкальный бот для Discord

Tags: python, discord, бот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать музыкального бота для **Discord** на **Python**? Пересмотрел почти весь интернет, ничего не нашел.

Comment: А что такое "музыкальный бот"? С вашей точки зрения? О том, что вы "Пересмотрел почти весь интернет, ничего не нашел." -   советую стереть. Признаваться в своем неумении пользоваться Гууглом не стоит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего использовать модуль wavelink, [здесь](https://github.com/PythonistaGuild/Wavelink/blob/master/examples/advanced.py) есть рабочий пример, так же для работы с wavelink вам нужен lavalink